# How to check that value exist in YII Session Variable

Tags: php, arrays, session, yii, session-variables

I am using yii and creating a cart, by using id of product i need to check that id already exists or not , but i use in_array and array_key_exists  but unable to solve it Here is my code of controller

```
public function actionCartupdateajax() {
        //start yii session
        $session = Yii::app()->session;
        // get posted values
        $id = isset($_POST['id']) ? $_POST['id'] : "";
        $name = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : "";
        $price = isset($_POST['price']) ? $_POST['price'] : "";
        $imgSrc = Yii::app()->request->baseUrl . '/images/icondeletecart.png';
        /*
         * check if the 'cart' session array was created
         * if it is NOT, create the 'cart' session array
         */
        if (!isset($session['cart_items']) || count($session['cart_items']) == 0) {
            Yii::app()->session['cart_items'] = array();
        }
        /*
         * Here is the proble
         *  check if the item is in the array, if it is, do not add 
         */
        if (in_array($id, Yii::app()->session['cart_items'])) {
            echo 'alreadyadded';
        } else {
            Yii::app()->session['cart_items'] = $id;
            echo '<li><strong>' . $name . '</strong><span>' . $price . '</span>'
            . '<img src=' . $imgSrc . ' alt="No Image" class="imagedeletecart" id=' . $id . '></li>';
        }
    }
```

and the error in console is

in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think problem in next row:

```
Yii::app()->session['cart_items'] = $id;
```

After this code cart_items will be NOT array, but integer or string.
Clear session and try to change:

```
Yii::app()->session['cart_items'][] = $id;
```

And better use [CHtml](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml) for generation html. It is cleaner. Like this:

```
echo CHtml::tag('li', array(/*attrs*/), 'content_here');
//your code 
echo '<li><strong>' . $name . '</strong><span>' . $price . '</span>'
            . '<img src=' . $imgSrc . ' alt="No Image" class="imagedeletecart" id=' . $id . '></li>';

//I propose this way(but you can use your version):
echo CHtml::tag(
            'li',
            array(),
            CHtml::tag(
                'strong',
                array(),
                'name'
            ) . CHtml::tag(
                'span',
                array(),
                'price'
            ) . CHtml::image(
                'src',
                'alt',
                array(
                    'class' => 'imagedeletecart',
                    'id' => 'id'
                )
            )
        );
```

Comment: if (!isset($session['cart_items']) || count($session['cart_items']) == 0) {
            $session->add('cart_items', array($id));        
        } else {
            if (in_array($id, $session['cart_items'])) {
                echo 'alreadyadded';
            } else {
                $cartItems = $session['cart_items'];
                $cartItems[] = $id;
                $session->add('cart_items', $cartItems);   
            }
        }

Comment: #Danila Ganchar I have solve session issue but will you please tell me how i create response html using above in echo CHtml::tag('li', array(/*attrs*/), 'content_here');

Comment: public function actiondeleteproductajax() {
        $session = Yii::app()->session;
        $id = isset($_POST['id']) ? $_POST['id'] : "";
        $key = array_search($id, $session['cart_items']);
        if ($key !== false)
            unset($session['cart_items'][$key]);
    }

Comment: Please have a look at function actiondeleteproductajax , when i want to remove value form session got messge Indirect modification of overloaded element of CHttpSession has no effect thanks in advance

Comment: echo '<pre>';
        Yii::app()->session['cart_items'] = array(1,2,3,5);
        print_r(Yii::app()->session->getKeys());
        Yii::app()->session->offsetUnset('cart_items');
        print_r(Yii::app()->session->getKeys());
        echo '</pre>';
        die();